# iOS Swift Button No Longer Working When Constraint Updated Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am updating the constraint of an image object in viewDidLoad.  After doing this a button whose constraints are related to the image object no longer works when pressed.  When I remove the constraint updating code the button works again.

I found that the frame size of the button changes to a height of zero after the image constraint is changed but if I try to change the height it does nothing.

The button shows up on screen same way in all situations, just cannot be pressed.

The code I am using to update image constraint:

```
let newConstraint = whiteTopConstraint.constraintWithMultiplier(0.45)

view.removeConstraint(whiteTopConstraint)

view.addConstraint(newConstraint)

view.layoutIfNeeded()

whiteTopConstraint = newConstraint
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Please share full code.

Comment: This is not how you set constraints programatically. You can update a constraint for which you have a IBOutlet created . For example  - whiteTopConstraint.constant = 20 (some integer). For more info you can check this - https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/2719/setting-constraints-programmatically

Comment: Yes, @Help is right. First you need to create a UIButton constraint Outlet and then you can update constraint without any difficulty.